# redirect subfolder to root with <subfolder-name>.html using htaccess

Tags: html, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have website that has links like

```
domain-name.com/pages/contact-us/
www.domain-name.com/pages/contact-us/
domain-name.com/pages/about-us/
www.domain-name.com/pages/about-us/
and other pages ...
```

What I'm looking for how i can redirect them permanently to same subfoldername.html using htaccess . for example for all the links above should redirected to

```
domain-name.com/contact-us.html
www.domain-name.com/contact-us.html
domain-name.com/about-us.html
www.domain-name.com/about-us.html
also for other pages, otherwise if page not found to root index.html .
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you always want to cute `pages` subfolder from the link? Or is this just a mistake?

Comment: yes, cute "pages" always .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(/pages/(.*[^/])/?)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%2.html [L,R=302]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.html [L,R=302]
```

The first three lines will remove the folder `pages`. If there is a trailing slash, it will be removed. The last three lines will redirect to `/index.html`, if the request file does not exist.

Comment: i'm getting it like domain-name.com/contact-us/.html ! i tried to remove / but it didn't help ? The 2nd part its works as the webserver can't find domain-name.com/contact-us/.html so its redirect you to index.html

Comment: I updated the answer in favour to that mistake. It should work now.

Comment: strange now its always redirect me to domain-name.com/index.html when i click on http://domain-name.com/pages/contact-us/ although the file contact-us.html is exists on root directory!

Comment: yeah you are right, the removal of the trailing slash was wrong. Now the redirect should work, with and without trailing slashes.